# largest term in simple continued fraction of $\sqrt{n}$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $n$ be a positive integer that is not a perfect square.  It is well known that the simple continued fraction of $\sqrt{n}$ is of the form
$$\sqrt{n} = [a_0;\overline{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{k-1},2a_0}],$$
where of course $a_0 = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$.  My question is, is $2a_0$ the maximum of all of the terms $a_i$ in the given continued fraction?  I'm unable to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. The partial quotients of a continued fraction expansion of the square root of a non square integer $n$, written $\sqrt{n}=[a_0;\overline{a_1, a_2, ..., a_{k-1},2a_0}]$,  with primitive period $k_p$, have the property $a_i\leqslant a_0$ for $k_p\nmid i$. For non primitive period, $a_i\leqslant 2a_0$, when $i\geqslant 0$.

Proof.
Let the complete quotients of the expansion of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{n}$ be denoted $r_h=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}+A_{h-1}}{\alpha_{h-1}}$, with $r_0=\sqrt{n}$.
Using the following properties ($h\geqslant 0$, $j\geqslant -1$):

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;A_j\leqslant a_0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$(Perron p.76 formula 7)

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;A_{h-1}+A_h=a_h\alpha_{h-1}\;\;\;\;\;$ (Perron p.83 formula 4)

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(3)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\alpha_{i-1}\geqslant 2 \text{ for } 0<i<k_p\;\;$ (Perron p.93 formula 5)

(Note:above indices are shifted for $A_h$ and $\alpha_h$ compared to Perron's notations)

(2) and (1) gives $a_h\leqslant \dfrac{2a_0}{\alpha_{h-1}}$, and using (3) we get $a_i\leqslant a_0$ for $0<i<k_p$ and by periodicity, for all $a_i$ with $k_p\nmid i$. And since all $\alpha_{h-1}$ for $h\geqslant0$ are positive integers, we have $a_h\leqslant 2a_0$ for $h\geqslant0$, the period being primitive or not.

[Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen (Perron)](https://archive.org/details/dielehrevondenk00perrgoog)

Comment: Thank you!  What do you mean by primitive period?  I haven't heard that term before.  And can one also conclude that $2a_0$ only occurs once in a given period, so all other terms are strictly less than $2a_0$?

Comment: @Jesse Elliott, the term "primitive period" was used by Perron (see comment end of page 73 of the link) and is synonym of "of the shortest period", or period of "minimal length" (since a a multiple of a period is also a (non-primitive) period). Yes, all other terms in the period are $\leq a_0$, so strictly less than $2a_0$

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying.  It makes sense to me now!